# I cannot valid a form with password and password confirm with angular 1.3.2

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a register form with input password and passwordConfirm as follow :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" ng-minlength=8 placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" required>
            </div>
                        <!-- error -->
            <div class="error" ng-show="userForm.inputPassword.$dirty && userForm.inputPassword.$invalid">
                <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.inputPassword.$error.required"> Your password is required. </small> 
                <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.inputPassword.$error.minlength"> Your password is required to be at least 8 characters </small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordConfirm"  id="passwordConfirm"  placeholder="Check your password" ng-model="passwordConfirm" required pw-check="user.password">
            </div>
            <!-- error -->
            <div class="error" ng-show="userForm.passwordConfirm.$dirty && userForm.passwordConfirm.$invalid">
                <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.passwordConfirm.$error.noMatch"> Passwords don't match </small>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In Chrome console, when the input are pristine (not yet filled), this is how it's look passwordConfirm:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Check your password" ng-model="passwordConfirm" required="" pw-check="user.password">
```

When i fill the password, i have the following error classes :

```
<input type="password" class="form-control ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-invalid-parse ng-valid-no-match ng-touched" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Check your password" ng-model="passwordConfirm" required="" pw-check="user.password">
```

What is the ng-invalid-parse ? I did not find documentation on it. I think this parse error causes ng-invalid so my form is invalid.

pw-check is a directive defined as follow :

```
app.directive('pwCheck', [function () {
return {

    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
            var noMatch = viewValue != scope.userForm.inputPassword.$viewValue
            ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch)
        })
    }

}
}]);
```

How to resolve it please ?

Comment: what is pw-check?? can you share code of that?

Comment: it's a directive. I add it